# Rails 4 mailer not firing - Not working in Letter Opener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, actionmailer

I have a rails mailer that I can't seem to get to work. I have a `listings` model and a `listing_status_change` model. When a listing is updated, I need to send an email with the person who changed the status. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

listing_mailer.rb

```
class ListingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "help@nooklyn.com"

  def status_change_notification(listing_change, sendee)
    @change_agent = listing_change.agent
    @listing = listing_change.listing
    @sendee = sendee
    @status = listing_change.humanable_status

    to_address = "#{@sendee.first_name} <#{@sendee.email}>"
    subject = "Listing Status Change: #{@listing.address.truncate(25)}"
    mail(to: to_address, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

status_change_notification.html.erb

```
Hiya <%= @sendee.first_name %>,<br><br>

The following listing changes were made:<br><br>

Listing: <%= @listing.address %><br><br>
Status: <%= @status %><br><br>
Changed By: <%= @change_agent.name %><br><br>

<%= link_to "Listing", @listing %>
```

change_status.rb

```
def send_notification_email(sendee)
  ListingMailer.status_change_notification(change_record, sendee)
    .deliver_later
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "listing_status_changes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "listing_id"
  t.integer  "agent_id"
  t.integer  "status"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: is your `send_notification_email` being fired ?, have you tried putting a `binding.pry` there to see if it is firing ?

Comment: @fanta Where should I put it?

Comment: before the `ListingMailer.status_change_notification...` line.

Comment: Try using deliver_now method instead of deliver_later ? Make sure you have everything set up properly as well.

Comment: @c0de222 It was working fine right before I added Changed By: <%= change_agent.name %><br><br>. I think the problem is in there or how I am trying to get the change_agent.name.